# junit - share a fixture between testcase

Tags: tdd, junit

I wonder whether it is possible to have a fixture that can be shared between testcases, for instance a hibernate session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all your tests (not testcases) to share the same hibernate session ?

Create it in your setUp() method, only if it has not been already created, and store it in a static member of your testcase class, similar to a singleton implementation.